# How do I reinstall OX without DVD & with new HDD after old HDD destroyed

Tags: macos, reinstall, installer

I have a MacBook Pro. The HDD had a catastrophic failure, so I replaced it with a brand new SSD. Therefore, my main drive is completely blank.

I lost my original OSX install DVD.

A replacement installer can only be had from the Apple Store, which is only accessible from OSX. (I tried from my Windows PC and received an error saying so.)

So how do I get past this impass?

PS: I need to download a version of OSX compatible with my laptop, but the 1pt engraving on the bottom of the laptop designating my model number wore off years ago. And obviously, I can't query Finder for it. Again, what do I do?

PPS: I have a MacBook Pro that does not have the ability to boot from the Internet.

Comment: Do you have any friends who have Macs?

Comment: Also, does your MacBook Pro have a DVD drive and have you previously downloaded the required OS X version from the App Store?

Comment: The simplest way, especially if you don't know which Mac it is, is to take it to an Apple Store; they'll do it for you. You really do need access to another Mac to even get started - https://support.apple.com/HT202294 might be useful, if so.

Comment: Moved to new city recently, no local friends

Comment: I do have DVD drive, but did not previously download installer. I am recovering from an unscheduled catastrophe and did not know I needed the installer!

Comment: I guess I will go to Apple Store. Will they charge money? I should not need to pay or leave home to fix a basic problem like this. There is no good reason for prohibiting me from downloading installer from a Windows machine.

Comment: If your MacBook Pro is old enough to run Snow Leopard (models first released in early 2011 and earlier), you can buy Snow Leopard install disks from Apple or on eBay.

Comment: They're unlikely to charge, they tend to do this type of task just out of goodwill. Re your complaint about 'pay or leave home' it's no-one else's responsibility but yours to ensure you have disaster recovery plans in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to take it to an Apple store and have them do that for you, or hook up with a friend who can do that for you.

If you had the original disk installed, then you might be able to do a recovery boot or a network boot, but neither of those options are available to you if you have replaced that drive with a blank SSD.

I don't think there's any way around the problem of getting a legitimate copy of the media either on DVD or Flash drive, and doing that either through an Apple authorized dealer or a friend who is willing to help.

Sorry!